# Changing z-order of draw method in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, z-index

Right now I am trying to draw a polygon in Cocos2d, but I need it over a background, how do I change draw's z-index and make it top priority so that way I can see the line instead of it being covered by the background?

Here is the draw method:

I decided to just make it a line instead of polygon, and adjust the width of it but otherwise it is the same...

```
-(void) draw {
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glLineWidth(5.0f);
    ccDrawLine(healthBar[0], healthBar[1]);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288222/primitives-and-sprites-z-index-in-cocos2d-x-3-0-is-not-consistent and I dont know how to solve. `reorderChhild` is not the solution yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reorderChild` function of CCNode. And put your rectangle over background

```
-(void) reorderChild:(CCNode *) child z:(int) zOrder
```

Comment: @Andrew: In the -(void) draw method.

Comment: @Andrew: I have posted the code of the draw method if that helps... But the class is really large and filled with other nonsense such as game logic etc.

Comment: @anon: Actually it's important when you method is called. Is your class is a subclass of CCSprite or CCNode ?

Comment: @Andrew: CCColoredLayer is what I subclassed my class with, and actually, Moshe brings up a point: the draw method is called lasted in the all the drawing for Cocos2d, and since Cocos2d is 2D and uses OpenGL ES the order in which stuff is drawn is drawn is important, I might need to change the internals a little... or make some change to my design... hmmm...

Comment: @anon: maybe it would be a solution creating one more layer and, putting it over background and drawing on it then ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate, you need to modify your GLView so that it has depth enabled. Then, you should be able to modify the depth of your draw call. In your app delegate, look for something like this:

```
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                    // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];
```

Change the `0` to either `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES` or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES`.

**Edit:**

I'm not familiar with OpenGL, but perhaps [this page](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) will help you.

Comment: I am confused as to what I need to do exactly: Where is this director? Where is this GL View? And is ccDrawLine a CCNode (I didn't think so) and where do I change its vertexZ property?

Comment: There is reorderChild function of CCNode. vertexZ is not for this

Comment: @Moshe: Ok, I am still confused though: Where do I change the z-index value for the draw method?

Comment: @anon please show your draw method or at least the relevant code.

Comment: @Moshe: Ok the draw method is now in the question.

Comment: @Moshe: Unfortunately no, I can't use the depth buffer (for a 2d using Cocos2d), the thing that determines the z-index is not the depth but, the order in which the elements are drawn, and in my case `-(void) draw` is called last and I need it to be called first somehow or something like that... But thanks for the try.

Comment: Well I rea somewhere (when dealing with a different issue), is that the depth and the drawing order internally. You'll have to do some hacking with the innards of cocos2d then.